# Break line after specific expression and add to running list

Tags: python, regex

I have very long text files with running measurements. These measurements are divided by some information that has almost the same style within my text files. Here an original extract:

```
10:10 10 244.576 0 0
10:20 10 244.612 0 0
10:30 10 244.563 0 0
HBCHa 9990 Seite 4
16.02.16
Hafenpegel 
Pegel müM Var 0 Pegelstand
Datum Zeit Intervall müM Q Art
Sonntag, 2. Januar 2000 10:40 10 244.555 0 0
10:50 10 244.592 0 0
11:00 10 244.595 0 0
11:10 10 244.593 0 0   
...
```

I would like a running list only with the measurements. As you can see, one measurement stands within an information line, in the line that starts with `Sonntag`. My problem is that I want to break the line after `2000` and add the second part of the broken line, `10:40 10 244.555 0 0`, as a separate line.

My target is this:

```
10:20 10 244.612 0 0
10:30 10 244.563 0 0
10:40 10 244.555 0 0
10:50 10 244.592 0 0
11:00 10 244.595 0 0
11:10 10 244.593 0 0
...
```

Until now I managed to choose the lines only that start with the time:

```
if i.startswith("0") or i.startswith("1") or i.startswith("2"):
```

and add it to new list.

And I can select the lines that contain the expression "tag":

```
f = open(source_file, "r")
data = f.readlines()

for lines in data:
    if re.match("(.*)tag(.*)", lines):
        print lines
```

There are no other lines that match with "tag"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to worry about the invalid information if you can precisely match the valid information. So we'll use a regular expression to match only the data we want.

```
import re

MEASUREMENT_RE = re.compile(r"\b\d{2}:\d{2} \d{2} \d{3}.\d{3} \d \d\b")

with open(source_file, mode="r") as f:
    print "\n".join(MEASUREMENT_RE.findall(f.read()))
```

Changes:

- context manager (`with` block) used to open the file so the file closes automatically
- `read` used instead of `readlines` since there's no point in applying a regular expression to each line instead of to all lines
- measurements found with a regular expression that checks for exactly the digits you're looking for (if you need to match more digits in any section, it should be altered)
- word boundaries (`\b`) used in regular expression to enforce whitespace or beginning/end of string is found around the match

Answer (score 0):

This one matches digit sequences of variable length separated by colon, space and full stop:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\d+:\d+ \d+ \d+.\d+ \d+ \d+')

with open(source_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line_clean = p.findall(line)
        if any(line_clean):
            print "".join(line_clean)
```